# What does "squint and read" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/cUyMnGeZ_3c?t=84)

> I am going to say that I'm
>   gonna do like a lot of simplifications
>   for the sake of the fact that this is a
>   30-minute talk.
>
> and if you can squint and read C you should be pretty fine with this talk.

lots of posts like [this one](https://twitter.com/kyalbr/status/1085675763016368135) are using the phrase "squint and read" as well.

what does that mean? does "squint and read" mean "trying the best to read", "to take a glance", or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he means is:

> This talk is only 30 minutes long so I will be simplifying things. You'll
>   understand it better if you read C.

"Squint and read" seems to be a faddish idiom. *To squint at* something means *to peer at it with one or both eyes narrowed in order to see it more clearly*. [One may also squint at a bright light to protect one's eyes.] The correct expression would be "squint **at** and read (something)".

A squint meme appeared around 2013, possibly originating with this picture:

https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/13765115/Senior-Chang-Squinting

And soon several variations, including a "squint read" meme, began appearing. Evidently these were popular enough to give rise to "squint read" as a vogue expression.

When the lecturer says, "I'm **gonna** do **like** a lot of simplifications" and "you should be fine with this talk" he is using the language of young people; trying to show he's [down with the kids.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105215/what-does-get-down-with-the-kids-or-be-down-with-the-kids-mean) He uses the expression "squint and read" similarly, to persuade them he is cool.

Answer (score 0):

The words ‘squint and read’ means to read something with your eyes somewhat closed or half-closed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is always better to provide proof for your answer, for example, a link that describes the meaning of the phrase